# Single Pane of Glass to manage pipelines

Tags: devops, cicd

One of my clients is all over the place with their devops environment.  Running multiple different CI/CD pipelines such as Jenkins, Bamboo etc.  Can someone suggest a product to manage different CI/CD pipelines from a single pane of glass.  How about Harness and Katalon Studio? I did reserach on both, but don't see to provide the expected outcome.  Any suggestions.

Best,

Research on a few products, but confused about the outcome

Comment: What will be the exact issue why these two solutions are not providing a solution? as both seems to integrate several tools. It seems like Harness has a better opensource solution you can try.

Comment: Thank you!  Sorry for the confusion, the question I was trying to ask if there a solution/product that can work as overlay to manage different CI/CD servers just as Jenkins and Bamboo